# How to make Tag Aliases

Tags: plugin-recommendation, tags, php

How would I build something like [this](http://www.librarything.com/tag/science+fiction) with wordpress.  Where multiple tags texts all go to the same page.
[image]

If you click on the tag "scifi" it takes you to tag "science fiction".  I am not looking for a way to merge them.

I want the tag text to vary, but the end page to be the same.  Any Ideas?

A physical redirect shouldn't be needed.  The tag text of X needs to be linked to Y when wordpress builds the link.

**Example:** If I type "scifi" as a tag, and the link gets build as 
`<a href="/tag/science fiction">scifi</a>` and therefore the tag is an alias for "science fiction".

Where would I hook in to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Have *not* tested tested yet, but I see in the Codex page for [wp_insert_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) there's one argument `alias_of`, which is described:

> There is no default, but if added, expected is the slug that the term
>   will be an alias of. Expected to be a string.

Maybe it helps ;)

Comment: I talked about this one to some core people some month ago. Point is: It's there, but not implemented :)

Comment: Oh! so close to a baked in solution :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best would be to simply merge synonyms. You can use [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/merge-tags/) plugin - @scribu is a trusted author.

Comment: However, I said in my question "I am not looking for a way to merge them"

Comment: Yea, I know. I thought about redirecting, but if you're going to have a lot of synonyms, then everything will slow down (and I'm talking about _really_ slow). Just check the "description" meta tag in your links head. What they're doing is not really good...

Answer (score 0):

I can use the  term_link filter, for the linking half of this problem:

Here is a basic,still hard coded, version:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Tag Alias
Version: 0.001
Plugin URI: 
Description: Adams Tag Alias -> hard coded tag redirects
Author: Adam
*/

$aliases = array (
    "450"  => "400",
    "speed controler" => "esc",
    "kds" => "esc"
);

function tagAliasFilter ($termlink, $term, $taxonomy) {
    global $aliases;
    foreach ($aliases as $alias => $key)
    if($term->slug == $alias)
    {
        $termlink = str_replace($alias,$key,$termlink);     
    }   
    return $termlink;
}
add_filter('term_link', 'tagAliasFilter',10,3);
?>
```

Now what is missing is pulling in the aliases on the tag pages